# database table design question

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have three tables (definitions below). My question is there can be multiple "bar" rows per "foo" row. So I need a "fooToBar" table. Is this the right design? What is the name or design pattern of for this type of situation? is there a better name for the table than "fooToBar" table? Thank you very much.

**foo**
fooID
name

**bar**
barID
name

**fooToBar**
fooID
barID

Comment: If there are only multiple bar rows per foo row, then you put a foreign key from the foo table into the bar table.  The only reason you would need an intersection table between foo and bar, is if the tables had a many to many relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design you name is for n:m relationships. If foo and bar are independent of each other and each foo can be related to several bars - and also each bar can be related to several foos, then this is the approach to go.

If each bar can only be related to one foo, you're in 1:n relationships and could just add a fooID column to the bar table.

I'd say if you keep the naming convention in your whole database, then there's no problem with this name (but correct the capitalization).

Comment: how should it be capitalized?

Comment: just consistent. you're having foo, bar, fooToBar - seeing this, you could argue to start with lowercase and then camel casing, but my first recognition was that you had "bar" as well as "Bar" in the names. It's personal taste - I'd have this consistent, but you might as well use this technique consistently (I really didn't see the principle in your capitalization when I answered).

Answer (score 1):

If there can be multiple **bars** for a single **foo**, but not the other way around, then you have what is called a **[one-to-many relationship](http://www.databaseprimer.com/relationship_1tox.html)** between **foo** and **bar**. To model such a relationship you would add a column named `fooId` in **bar**. There would be no need for a **fooToBar** table.

However, if there can both be multiple **bars** for a single **foo** *and* multiple **foos** for a single **bar** then you have a [**many-to-many relationship**](http://www.databaseprimer.com/relationship_xtox.html) between **foo** and **bar**, which necessitates a third join table (**fooToBar**).

Regarding naming convention, I usually use proper casing (not camel casing), and affix each database object with a prefix that identifies the application the object belongs to. Also, I usually name my many-to-many join tables so that they incorporate the names of the other two tables. For example, if I was building Stackoverflow, I might prefix each database object with **so**, meaning my tables in the many-to-many example would be named:

- so_Foo
- so_Bar
- so_FoosBars

I think what is more important than the naming minutia is that you choose a convention and stick with it.

Happy Programming!

Answer (score 0):

You need the FooToBar table if the foo bar relationship is optional, i.e. if you want to allow Bar rows that have no corresponding Foo row. Otherwise you could just put the foo attribute as a foreign key in bar.